# cannot load vue file when installed in node_modules

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I would like to use a 3rd party plugin but can't get it to load with my webpack config because the vue-loader isn't configured properly ( I think )
Importing my own components which are in the project folder works.

```
import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate.vue'
```

When trying to import a .vue file from a package I get this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <template>

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

So I think the vue-loader doesn't work if I import a package which is within node_modules folder.

This is my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const vueConfig = require('./vue-loader.config')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  devtool: isProd
    ? false
    : '#cheap-module-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'public': path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')
    }
  },
  module: {
    noParse: /es6-promise\.js$/, // avoid webpack shimming process
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules\/,
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: isProd
          ? ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
              use: 'css-loader?minimize',
              fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
            })
          : ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  performance: {
    maxEntrypointSize: 300000,
    hints: isProd ? 'warning' : false
  },
  plugins: isProd
    ? [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          compress: { warnings: false }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: 'common.[chunkhash].css'
        })
      ]
    : [
        new FriendlyErrorsPlugin()
      ]

}
```

vue-loader.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  extractCSS: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  preserveWhitespace: false,
  postcss: [
    require('autoprefixer')({
      browsers: ['last 3 versions']
    })
  ]
}
```

The node_modules is excluded but shouldn't it only be excluded for the babel-loader, not the vue loader itself ?

---- edit

I'm using SSR, the author itself states in this [issue](https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate/issues/44)

> @johnRivs Thank you so much. @sbefort You can import the library by
>   import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate'; for
>   SSR. Any question please reopen this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to go into the NPM package internals.

When you do:

```js
import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate.vue'
```

notice you depend on `vuejs-paginate`'s internals (`src` folder exists?) and such.

The propert way is to **install** the package and import what the package exposes.

---

For example, to install, run on shell:

```
npm install vuejs-paginate --save
```

Then in your code, import and use like:

```js
import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate'
Vue.component('paginate', Paginate)
```

And WebPack will take care of the rest, independently (at least with regards to `vuejs-paginat` itself) from the `vue-loader`. And, yes, `vue-loader` should exclude `node_modules` because you don't want it to process every soucve `.vue` file of every package you import.

Comment: I'm using SSR, https://github.com/lokyoung/vuejs-paginate/issues/44 - the author itself states @sbefort You can import the library by import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate'; for SSR.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks for your constructive comment, but I did read it, not only the manual but also the issues, since it doesn't work for me I think it's my webpack conf.

Comment: @user345234674567 In your question you say you are including the extension `.vue`, like: `import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate.vue'`. Have you tried it without it, like `import Paginate from 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate';`?

Comment: @acdcjunior yes I've already tried that, can't find the module at all this way - Error: Cannot find module 'vuejs-paginate/src/components/Paginate' from '/home/user/ssr/dist'

Comment: Did you `npm install --save vuejs-paginate`?